# Can't get Unicode font to work with three.js TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to animate unicode text using three.js TextGeometry.

Text is: "Saint-Étienne-du-Mont"
It appears in Canvas as "Saint-??tienne-du-Mont"

Refer this [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50158740/unicode_error.png)

Code:

```
var text3d = new THREE.TextGeometry( theText, {
    size: 80,
    height: 20,
    curveSegments: 0,
    font: "ubuntu"
});
```

Here is the link to my webpage: [test_canvas](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50158740/canvas_test/canvas.html)

Comment: The last line of your program should call `animate()`, not `render()`.

Comment: @WestLangley I'm calling render from some other function. I'm sorry I didn't mention it there. But even if I call animate the unicode characters comes as "??". Refer this [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50158740/unicode_error.png)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the solution, but I would suggest you rewrite your question to make it clear what the problem is. Saying it doesn't "work" is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a simple encoding problem. The web page is UTF-8, but you have pasted in text encoded with some other character set (possibly cp1252 from a windows machine). You can see this by viewing the source of your web page -- the É character is messed up in there as well.

For comparison, here is a [simplified version of your page](http://gamingjs.com/ice/#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) with the text correctly encoded.

Not all JS fonts will handle UTF-8 characters. The default helvetiker from Three.js, for instance, will render the É as a question mark.

Comment: It turns out that it was issue with Dropbox. They have a bug which doesn't let you serve webpage in UTF-8.